# Is it possible to convert a lottie animation to a GIF?

Tags: gif, lottie

I know Lottie animations are far superior to GIFs in terms of size, control, and quality. I'm looking for a way to convert a single Lottie animated as I don't want to include extra javascript resources in a project. Is there a way to convert a Lottie animation to a GIF or another moving image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use https://lottiefiles.com/lottie-to-gif to convert your Lottie animations to GIF.

Comment: This feature wasn't (publicly) available when I asked this question, however I believe this as of May 2020 is the best way to do this as a one-time operation.

Comment: This works but its very limited in resolutions, and opaque background colors don't seem to work (on Firefox at least, or they didn't work with my particular animation)

Comment: I was unable to create a GIF with transparent background. :| Also, the GIF conversion is very slow!

Comment: You can use another tool in here: https://lilas-dev.github.io/lottie2gif/

Comment: I made tool to convert lottie animations. The conversion is done in your browser. https://abichinger.github.io/lottie-alchemist/

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned here: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/1614 there is a javascript library for this.
It's called [puppeteer-lottie](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/puppeteer-lottie).
They also provide a [command line interface](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/puppeteer-lottie-cli)

I used it once and the output was not as good as the original lottie animation but ok. I just used the default settings.

Comment: As a note, I had a lot more successful results when I generated PNGs ([like the first line here](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/puppeteer-lottie-cli/issues/15)) and then merged them with ffmpeg with a command like `ffmpeg -y -framerate 60 -i frame-%d.png -filter_complex "[0:v] fps=50,split [a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse" out.gif`. This removes the transparency, but drops the gifski dependency and gets rid of glitchy graphics.